# Why isn't the __del__ method called？

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, circular-reference, finalizer

In python3's `multiprocess`,  can't call the `__del__` method.

I've read other issues about circular references,but I can't find the situation in `multiprocess`.

There is a circular reference in `foo`, `__del__` will be called when  `foo` is called directly,but in `multiprocess` the `__del__` will never be called.

```
import multiprocessing
import weakref


class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = []

    def __del__(self):
        print ('del')


def foo():
    print ('call foo')
    f = Foo()
    a = [f]
    # a = [weakref.ref(f)]
    f.b.append(a)


# call foo in other process
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
p.start()
p.join()


# call foo
foo()
```

**Output:**
*call foo

call foo

del*

why `__del__` is not called in `p`?

Comment: What do you think `weakref` does? You mention it in your code, and it's related to this question, but you don't say why you think it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forked `Process` objects terminate after running their task using [`os._exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit), which forcibly terminates the child process *without* the normal cleanup Python performs on exit. Cyclic garbage isn't cleaned (because the process is terminated without giving the cyclic GC a chance to run), it's just dropped on the floor, leaving the OS to clean up.

This is intentional, since exiting normally (invoking all normal cleanup procedures) would risk stuff like unflushed buffers getting flushed in both parent and child (doubling output), and other weirdness involved when a forked process inherits all the state of the parent but isn't supposed to use it except when told to do so explicitly.

You *could* write a wrapper function that would invoke the "real" function, then trigger a cycle collection before returning, but it's hard to write correctly and quite brittle. An initial stab at it would be something like:

```
import gc
import traceback

def clear_cycles_after(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    except BaseException as e:
        # Clear locals of all frames in the traceback
        traceback.clear_frames(e.__traceback__)  # Requires 3.4+
        raise  # Reraises original exception with locals cleaned from all frames
    finally:
        gc.collect()  # Now that we've cleaned the locals from any exception traceback,
                      # it should be possible to identify cyclic garbage
                      # and gc.collect() will clean it up
```

You'd use it by replacing:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
```

with:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=clear_cycles_after, args=(foo,))
```

I don't really recommend this solution though. Ideally, if some cleanup (not related to process memory, which the OS cleans for you anyway) must occur in the child, you'd implement [the context manager protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) on the relevant type(s) ([`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) can be used to provide such functionality for existing types you can't modify directly) and create/control them with [`with` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), which would guarantee cleanup was performed deterministically, even in the presence of cyclic references, even on non-CPython interpreters (which aren't reference counted, and therefore don't perform deterministic cleanup without `with` statements even when there are no cyclic references). Anything less than `with` statements (or `try`/`finally` blocks with equivalent effect) is going to be some combination of brittle, non-portable, or non-functional.

Using context management, your class and function would look like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = []

    def close(self):  # Convenient to have a way to manually clean up when needed
        print('del')
        del self.b[:]  # Clear contents of b to avoid cyclic references after cleanup

    # Optional: Provide __del__ as best effort in case user doesn't close or context managev
    __del__ = close
    
    # Define context management special methods in terms of shared close
    def __enter__(self):
        return self  # No-op when entering with block
    def __exit__(self, typ, exc, tb):
        self.close()


def foo():
    print ('call foo')
    with Foo() as f:  # Create and manage with with statement
        a = [f]
        f.b.append(a)
    # f's contents are cleaned here, so when foo returns, on CPython, a and f will be cleaned
    # since they're not part of a reference cycle anymore, and the actual Foo
    # object bound to f and a[0] will be removed deterministically
```

You'll actually see multiple `del` outputs now in some cases, particularly when you include the optional `__del__ = close` line as a backup when the user fails to context manage (where `close` and/or `__exit__` gets invoked, then `__del__` gets invoked later), but there's no harm there (the contained `list` just gets emptied twice).

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't actually why it *isn't* called in `multiprocess`, but why it *is* called in the other example. And the answer to that is that it isn't called when you call `foo`. It's called at the end of the program. Since the program is finished, Python knows that anything else can be cleaned up even if it's still referenced, so it cleans up circular references.

If you add a `print` statement at the end of the script, or call this from the REPL, you can see that `__del__` still isn't called at your second `foo` call either, but only at the end of the script.

Given that Python cleans up circular references when the script ends, [ShadowRanger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46966357/27302) explains why that doesn't happen when the multiprocessing function is finished.

Comment: Python cleans circular references intermittently, not just at script termination. Much of the details are documented on [the `gc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html), but the short version is it maintains pools of monitored references by age, and cleans the newer pools more frequently, and the older pools less often, with the interval being determined by number of allocations and deallocations performed. That said, as long as one live (non-cyclic) reference exists, the cycle collection doesn't matter (since it's not yet cyclic garbage).

Comment: I was careful not to say it *only* happened then, but I did sort of imply it. I wasn't sure, but I thought it usually only happened then but there was something you could call in `gc` if you wanted or it probably checked if you were out of memory. It's good to know it sometimes happens before the end anyway.